# Scrapy Spider just crawls and does not scrape

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am making a project in which I have used scrapy to **scrape** items from web sites, but the problem is, the xpaths of the 1st 2 pages of that site is different from the xpaths of the other pages.
As the result my spider just scrapes the items from first two pages and just simply crawls over the other pages.
How can I make my spider also scrape the items of the pages too??

I am also including my spider here so that u can see through my spider if needed.

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from project2.items import Project2Item
from scrapy.http import Request

class ProjectSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "project2spider"
    allowed_domains = ["http://directory.thesun.co.uk/"]
    current_page_no = 1
    start_urls = [
        'http://directory.thesun.co.uk/find/uk/computer-repair'
        ]

    def get_next_url(self, fired_url):
        if '/page/' in fired_url:
            url, page_no = fired_url.rsplit('/page/', 1)
        else:
            if self.current_page_no != 1:
                #end of scroll
                return 
        self.current_page_no += 1
        return "http://directory.thesun.co.uk/find/uk/computer-repair/page/%s" % self.current_page_no

# the parse procedure, and here is the codes which declares which field to scrape. 
    def parse(self, response):
        fired_url = response.url
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select('//div[@class="abTbl "]')
   
        for site in sites:
            item = Project2Item()
            item['Catogory'] = site.select('span[@class="icListBusType"]/text()').extract()
            item['Bussiness_name'] = site.select('a/@title').extract()
            item['Description'] = site.select('span[last()]/text()').extract()
            item['Number'] = site.select('span[@class="searchInfoLabel"]/span/@id').extract()
            item['Web_url'] = site.select('span[@class="searchInfoLabel"]/a/@href').extract()
            item['adress_name'] = site.select('span[@class="searchInfoLabel"]/span/text()').extract()
            item['Photo_name'] = site.select('img/@alt').extract()
            item['Photo_path'] = site.select('img/@src').extract()
            #items.append(item)
            yield item
        next_url = self.get_next_url(fired_url)
        if next_url:
            yield Request(next_url, self.parse, dont_filter=True)
```

for other pages I need to use this: `sites = hxs.select('//div[@class="icListItem"]')`

How can I include this in my spider so that it can **scrape** items form other pages too..

At present its just scraping 1st two pages and simply crawls over other pages.

Comment: strange to see , in 9 hours no one gave any suggestions to solve this problem.
..Someone plz guide

Comment: Most likely not getting the feeling *you* wrote it... i.e: "how do I make this piece of code I don't understand do this extremely simple additional thing?" (without learning to program at all).

Comment: Argh. Completely unrelated to the question itself, but this has been bugging me ever since I first saw this code: "Category" not "Catogory", "Business_name" not "Bussines_name" and "address_name" not "adress_name". And breathe.

Comment: FYI it’s __scrape__ (and __scraper__, __scraping__, __scraped__) not scrap

Answer (score 0):

What did you try so far?
One solution would be using an index-like parameter passed as a meta data when calling for the next page. Something like:

```
def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    2nd_xpath = False
    try:
        if response.meta['index'] > 1:
            2nd_xpath = True
        index = response.meta['index']
    except KeyError:
        index = 0
    sites = (hxs.select('//div[@class="icListItem"]') if 2nd_xpath
             else hxs.select('//div[@class="abTbl "]'))

    ...

    request = Request(next_url, self.parse, dont_filter=True)
    request.meta['index'] = index + 1
    yield request
```

That code sure as hell can be improved but you get the idea.